# How to allow user's of a certain role to change the node creation date

Tags: 7

I want to allow some users (a role) to change the node creation date (ideally on the node's form).

[image]

- I could add permission 'administer nodes' to this role but it's too strong
- I could create a new field for this date, but i want to keep the drupal submitted informations on the top of the node

If someone have any idea, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the drupal submitted informations on the top of the node"? And I strongly suggest to split this question in 2 steps: 1) How to make date editable and 2) how to limit it to certain roles.

Comment: For example, a news is created today on my website, but the website is an old one, and the news should have been created 1 year ago. I want the allow the user to change the node's creation date, otherwise the submitted informations would be wrong with the current date

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module.

> The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each
>   field within the Authoring information and Publishing options field
>   sets on the node form. It also allows selected field sets to be set as
>   collapsed and / or collapsible.

In addition you may be interested in [Date Popup Authored](https://drupal.org/project/date_popup_authored) to use a datepicker on that field.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank U. Note that in the Date Popup Authored module a permission verification can make popup not working for non admin user: date_popup_authored_form_alter() line 122 $form['author']['#access'] is empty. Thank you again

Comment: more details here: https://drupal.org/node/1090164

Comment: update the override_node_options module's weight to -1 works

Comment: Oops I forgot about that. Now I remember, there's an [issue with a patch in override_node_options' queue](https://drupal.org/node/1090696) that has been already committed, but only available in -dev version by now.